# How to make jenkins build execution faster

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am facing problem using jenkins, I have ran one test case for 103 times, previously it used to run faster but not it is too slow.

Do I need to cleanup anything like logs?

I am using jenkins web interface

Please let me know

Comment: How many builds etc. do you retain?

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean the previous builds using the log rotation parameter?

For example, you can keep only the 10 latest builds or the builds for the 10 last days.

It can improve the performance if you are keeping a lot of builds.